# Visualforce Component to Lightning Component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

How do I know any visualforce component like apex:composition is supported in Lightning or not?
or how do I also know the corresponding Lightning component of any Visualforce component?

Comment: Have you tried looking for [LWC developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc)?

Comment: welcome to the community, can you please be more specific with your question, what do you mean by supported? Does it has analogues in LWC, Aura or can you use it with Visualforce in Lightning?

Comment: I am trying to mean that any visualforce component like apex:composition can be used in lightning?

Comment: No it cannot be. Since they are 2 different languages and follow different component architecture. Refer the lwc developer guide.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse Visualforce components (i.e `apex:composition`) inside Aura and LWC, but you can add your Visualforce pages to Lightning via App Builder or `iframe`) because new Salesforce UI frameworks are not backwards compatible, they are forward compatible.

It means that you can use Aura and LWC in Visualforce, but not vice versa.

If you want to learn Lightning development, please refer to Trailhead and LWC developer guide.